# How to display array of components in parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a webshop-like app that displays several items which can be added to a shopping cart. I have a StoreComponent which has an arrya of ItemComponents. I want to display all items in a table in the store.

I made a service who provides all items for the store. I was able to show the items from the store html template. Now i encapsulated the html in the item template, but I can't figure out how to display all my items now.

```
--- Store component ---
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {

  private items: ItemComponent[] = ItemService.get_items();
  constructor(itemService: ItemService) {}
}    

--- Item component ---
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _name: string, private _unitPrice: number, private 
 _description?:string, private _image?:string) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  get name(){return this._name;}
  get unitPrice(){return this._unitPrice}
  get description(){return this._description;}
  get image(){return this._image;}

}    

--- store component html (worked) ---
<div id="items">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>unitPrice</th>
  <th>description</th>
  <tr *ngFor='let item of items'>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.unitPrice}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>    

--- New Store component html (doesn't work) ---
<div id="items">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>unitPrice</th>
  <th>description</th>
    <app-item  *ngFor='let item of items'></app-item>
  </tr>
 </div>    

--- New Item component html (doesn't show) ---
<tr>
  <td>{{name}}</td>
  <td>{{unitPrice}}</td>
  <td>{{description}}</td>
</tr>


--- After I edited the html code, I get following error: ---

ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ItemComponent -> 
String]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ItemComponent -> String]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue : `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: For the error you have shown I think the mistake may be in the constructor of `ItemComponent`, but without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's really hard to tell. How do you expect these values (`private _name: string, private _unitPrice: number, private _description?:string, private _image?:string`) to be provided for you in that constructor?

Comment: I made an ItemService to create the ItemComponents:

    export class ItemService {

      constructor() { }

      static get_items(){
        return [
          new ItemComponent("brood", 2, "wit brood, vers gebakken"),
          new ItemComponent("choco", 1.5, "lekker op je boterham"),
          new ItemComponent("kaas", 1, "voor als je geen choco lust"),
          new ItemComponent("hesp", 1.1),
          new ItemComponent("plant", 8, "kamerplant")
        ];
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Since Item component is a child of parent component you can [pass data](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) from the parent (Store) to the child (Item) by using the Input decorator

```
--- Item Component --- 
export class ItemComponent implements onInit{
   @Input() item
}

--- Item component HTML ---
<tr>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.price}}</td>
  <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>

--- Store Component ---

<div id="items">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>unitPrice</th>
  <th>description</th>
    <app-item  *ngFor='let item of items' [item]="item"></app-item>
  </tr>
 </div>
```

Try it and let me know if you face any other troubles

Comment: I tried to add the input decorator, but I still get the same error (NullInjectorError: No provider for String!)

Comment: Sounds like you used 'String' instead of 'string' somewhere in the code, can you show me the service you're using?
Also please make sure that you clear the constructor in your Item Component

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass data to a component in Angular is NOT via constructor parameters, but via input properties (like @Yazan Shanak said).

The error you get comes from your constructor parameters in `ItemComponent`:

```js
@Component(...)
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  // INCORRECT
  // You can't inject the "string" type. You should inject service types.
  constructor(private _name: string, private _unitPrice: number...) { }

}
```

Remember, Angular uses class constructors for **dependency injection**. Your code is equivalent to saying to Angular: "inject a dependency of type "string" and then inject a dependency of type "number"..." But of course these dependencies don't make sense.

What you should do in `ItemComponent` is change your **constructor parameters** to **class properties**. Also, decorate these class properties with `@Input()` so you can set their values from the parent `StoreComponent`.

```js
@Component(...)
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() private name: string;
  @Input() private unitPrice: number;

  // DELETE the "string" and "number" params from the constructor
  constructor() { }

}
```

Then, update the HTML of `StoreComponent` to set the input properties of `ItemComponent` :

```html
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items" [name]="item.name" [price]="item.price"></app-item>
```

Note that it's suboptimal to pass each item property individually. You should create ONE input property called `item` and pass the entire item at once.

```html
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app-item>
```